# OfficeXmlFileException. How do I Solve this?

Tags: exception, apache-poi

Exception in thread

```
"main" org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.OfficeXmlFileException: The supplied data appears to be in the Office 2007+ XML. You are calling the part of POI that deals with OLE2 Office Documents. You need to call a different part of POI to process this data (eg XSSF instead of HSSF)
```

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the thread you should use `XSSF` over `HSSF` or another higher version API.
Also can you share your code snippet.